# Publish a javascript file on a C# publication

Tags: javascript, c#, .net

Just a quick question, so I might continue with my work or change it.

I want to implement a javascript file into the publication of a C# webapp its .NET and the publish is through visual studio.

**"node api.js"** would be the command

This js is an api, its just listening to a port for when a request come in. This js code, has nothing to do with the rest of the project.

I just want that when we publish the webapp the little js file executes in the back listening.

Is this possible?

Comment: are you using the dotnet cli to publish? If so, and you're on a *nix machine it could be as simple as "dotnet publish && node api.js". Not sure how you'd achieve the same effect with windows.

Comment: The publication is made through the UI interface, publish->and select the publish the startup.cs I might put the command in that startup file. Yeah its windows. hanks for your response.